# Как найти слово из списка в ячейке таблицы и вывести его?

Tags: excel

В таблице от поставщика много позиций без указания бренда производителя, но он может присутствовать в наименовании товара. Собственно нужно взять строку из ячейки и проверить есть ли в нем слово из диапазона с брендами и вывести его. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/ПОИСК(brands;B2);brands)
```

Comment: Забыли уточнить: `brands` - диапазон с брендами.---*ПОИСК* не учитывает регистр букв. Еще одно: если часть слова будет похожа на бренд,  функция определит его, как бренд. Для поиска полного соответствия: `=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/НАЙТИ(" "&brands&" ";" "&B2&" ");brands)`